# Cant use Opcache on my Nextcloud server

Tags: 16.04, server, apache2, php, nextcloud

I am following the official instruction on Nextclouds official webpage. I pasted in this text into /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini :

opcache.enable=1

opcache.enable_cli=1

opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8

opcache.max_accelerated_files=10000

opcache.memory_consumption=128

opcache.save_comments=1

opcache.revalidate_freq=1

and I still got the error message.
I use Ubuntu 16.04.3 and PHP7.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you: https://lastplaceonthe.net/how-to-enable-php-7-opcache-on-ubuntu-16-04/
In my case it worked like this:
Do not edit  `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`
Edit the file `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/opcache.ini`
And enable opcache mode `sudo phpenmod opcache`
And restart apache `sudo phpenmod opcache`